# Multiple APK for different ARM CPUs

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-play

I am developing an app, which heavily uses native code and require performance. GCC compiler can optimize code for different types of processors: Cortex-A9, Cortex-A7, Cortex-A15, et cetera. Some ARMv7 processors even don't have NEON instructions or implement it partially. Anyway, GCC knows about it.

I want to get maximum performance on an every device. But when I build my application with idiv support, application instantly crashes, for example, on Tegra 2. Compiling for Cortex-A15 gives great perfomance boost, but compiled code can't run on Cortex-A9.

So is there any way to publish multiple APKs not only by CPU ABI, but also for CPU model?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't get a finer granularity than with the CPU ABI.

What you can do is checking for cpu features at runtime using `cpufeatures` from the NDK, and load the right library or codepath.

Comment: In this case APK may be too fat.